# Reset shipping method on cart empty and order complete

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

Is it possible without a plugin?

Our client desperately wants the shipping method to be reset (not selected) after an order has been placed or the empty cart button is clicked.

Edit: The shipping method does indeed reset after a completed purchase. Apologies. Regardless, reset on empty cart is still an issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You're right, this does not seem to clear automatically when you remove all line items, but you could *I think* just set an extra post value in your form that calls `removeAllLineItems` to clear the shipping handle at the same time...because in this controller there is a call to `$cart->setContentFromPost('fields');` I presume if you set the shipping handle to `""`, that set content will cause the shipping method to be dropped from the cart.

So basically add `<input type="hidden" name="shippingMethod" value="">` to your form & it *should* work.

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the answer. Unfortunately it did not work. I tried on the default template code that comes with Commerce as well. Do you have other suggestions? Cheers!

Comment: Yeah I realised my answer above is not right - it might be setting custom `fields` at that point, but not the `shippingMethod`.

I think your best bet here is to ajax two requests off - one to `updateCart` to clear the shipping method/id, and then a second call to `removeAllLineItems` once that returns.  Hacky, but it will work.

Comment: Could you expand on the updateCart form. I don't understand how I can use that to clear the shipping method. I tried simply creating a form and submitting it, but nothing happens. Apologies in advance for being a bother here. Thank you! (The ajax part won't be a problem, no need to expand on that)